# Export to CSV file Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export the data to a CSV file but the output produced is different from what I want

```
word = "contoh"
vector = np.array([-0.6910377 ,  1.6553369 ,  0.6142262 ,  2.7324615 , -0.29642856])
list=(word,vector)
print(list)
print(len(vector))
ok=open('samp.csv','a')
a=csv.writer(ok)
a.writerows(list)
```

output from this code

```
c,o,n,t,o,h

-0.6910377 ,  1.6553369 ,  0.6142262 ,  2.7324615 , -0.29642856....
```

i want the output like this

`contoh,-0.6910377 ,  1.6553369 ,  0.6142262 ,  2.7324615 , -0.29642856...`

i want contoh and the number array to be in one row

please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to achieve, add a word to the `numpy` `array` and then save it as a `csv` file.

See a mock up below. Let me know if it works.

```
import csv
word = "contoh"
vector = np.array([-0.6910377 ,  1.6553369 ,  0.6142262 ,  2.7324615 , -0.29642856])
mylist= np.append(word,vector) #add word to vector
ok=open('samp.csv','a')
a=csv.writer(ok,lineterminator='\n')
a.writerows([mylist])
ok.close()
```

Result below (in `samp.csv`):

```
contoh,-0.6910377,1.6553369,0.6142262,2.7324615,-0.29642856
```